# Change view on notification

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm having a problem to change view when user press notification my code to set the rootPage is this one this code is inside the platform ready callback function:

```
this._authService.isAuthenticated().subscribe(
        success => {
          console.log('DashboardPage');
          this.rootPage = DashboardPage;
        },
        error => {
          console.log('LoginPage');
          this.rootPage = LoginPage;
        },
        () => {//After set the rootPage I call configPush
          this.splashScreen.hide();
          this.configPush();
        }
      )
```

My config push function:

```
private configPush() {
    push.on('registration', (data) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
      this._authService.setDeviceId(data.registrationId);
    });

    push.on('notification', (data) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data.additionalData));
      if (data.additionalData.foreground) {
        this.global.startToast(data.message)
      } else {
        if ((data.additionalData.contexto && data.additionalData.contexto == 'seguidores')) {
          this.app.getRootNav().setRoot(DashboardPage, { contexto: 'seguidores' });
        }
        if ((data.additionalData.contexto && data.additionalData.contexto == 'evento')) {
          console.log('entrou');
          let evento = JSON.parse(data.additionalData.evento);
          console.log(JSON.stringify(evento));
          this.app.getRootNav().push(EventoPage, { evento: data.additionalData.evento });
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

It actually enters in the if section when contexto == 'evento', but the push in the rootNav is not executed or if it's executed nothing happens, no errors in console anything, Is my code correct? How can I manage to change the view passing the params I get at the notification to the view that I want do change

Comment: what if you do getActiveNav() instead of getRootNav()?

Comment: Same thing, it enters inside the if section but then the command is executed and nothing happens :(